# Custom shadowmapping in Unity not working properly

Tags: unity, shaders, shadow-mapping, lighting

To experiment with a certain technique, I'm implementing my own shadow mapping in Unity. I'm using a camera for the light "view", which is rendered to a RenderTexture after being post-processed with the following shader:

```
Shader "Custom/DepthGrayscale" {
  SubShader {
     Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }

     Pass{
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        sampler2D _CameraDepthTexture;

        struct v2f {
           float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
           float4 scrPos:TEXCOORD1;
        };

        //Vertex Shader
        v2f vert (appdata_base v){
           v2f o;
           o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
           o.scrPos=ComputeScreenPos(o.pos);
           //for some reason, the y position of the depth texture comes out inverted
           o.scrPos.y = 1 - o.scrPos.y;
           return o;
        }

        //Fragment Shader
        half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR{
           float depthValue = tex2Dproj(_CameraDepthTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.scrPos)).r;

           return fixed4(depthValue, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        }
        ENDCG
     }
  }
  FallBack "Diffuse"
```

}

With a width and height of `2048` for the Render Texture and the color format `R Float` for 32-bit precision.

The objects in the scene then have the following shader that takes the `projection * view` matrix of the light and "depth" texture as input. (Basic shadow mapping with bias)

```
Shader "Tutorial/Display Normals" {
    Properties {
        _CameraTex ("Camera texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader {
        Pass {

            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            uniform float4x4 lightMatrix;

            struct v2f {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float3 worldPos : COLOR0;
                fixed3 color : COLOR1;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata_base v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                o.worldPos = v.vertex.xyz;
                o.color = v.normal * 0.5 + 0.5;
                return o;
            }

            uniform sampler2D _CameraTex;

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 coords = mul(lightMatrix, fixed4(i.worldPos, 1.0));
                coords /= coords.w;

                coords.x = (coords.x + 1.0) / 2.0;
                coords.y = (coords.y + 1.0) / 2.0;
                coords.z = (coords.z + 1.0) / 2.0;

                //return fixed4(coords.z, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
                float lightDepth = tex2D(_CameraTex, fixed2(coords.x, 1.0 - coords.y)).r;
                float depth = coords.z;

                if (depth < lightDepth + 0.005) {
                    return fixed4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                } else {
                    return fixed4(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
                }
            }
            ENDCG

        }
    }
}
```

The result of this is perfect with a plane and cube:

[image]

The red plane displays the shadow map and the camera represents the light.

However, when using a more complex model like Sibenik, the following happens:

[image]

When I move it slightly, the shadow on the plane is suddenly correct, but the shadow on the church model itself is still wrong:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the model matrix:

```
o.worldPos = mul(_Object2World, v.vertex).xyz;
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify the script to support multiple directional lights?

Comment: @BenBearFish I have no clue, it took a few days of research to get even this working.